# ListView showing parent View and wont take right view?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xml-parsing, android-listview

I am getting `XML` from a `Restfull` service request and need to display it in a `listView`.

I decided to emulate a similar function i found on an online blog and it seems to feed back the original View and not the view format i assign to the elements.

[image: error]

Now you can see its duplicated Twice.....After the My Move Contacts bar is where the `ListView` starts and then duplicates.

the XMl for the ListView:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>
```

As well the XML i am using for the Adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ContactTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MainPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CellPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Fax"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not very good with building these `ListViews` yet and know its something i did but i cant put my finger on it. Here is my Java for the handling of the data to `listView`:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            String xml = result;
            String KEY_ITEM = "Contact";
            String KEY_CONTACTTITLE = "ContactTitle";
            String KEY_NAME = "Name";
            String KEY_MAINPHONE = "Phone";
            String KEY_CELLPHONE ="Cell";
            String KEY_FAX = "Fax";
            String KEY_EMAIL= "Email";
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            Document doc = getDomElement(xml);
            if (xml != null) {
                {
                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                        map.put(KEY_CONTACTTITLE, getValue(e, KEY_CONTACTTITLE));
                        map.put(KEY_NAME, getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                        map.put(KEY_MAINPHONE, getValue(e, KEY_MAINPHONE));
                        map.put(KEY_CELLPHONE, getValue(e, KEY_CELLPHONE));
                        map.put(KEY_FAX, getValue(e, KEY_FAX));
                        map.put(KEY_EMAIL, getValue(e, KEY_EMAIL));
                        menuItems.add(map);
                    }

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MoveContactsActivity.this, menuItems,
                            R.layout.activity_move_contacts, new String[] {
                                    KEY_CONTACTTITLE, KEY_NAME, KEY_MAINPHONE, KEY_CELLPHONE, KEY_FAX, KEY_EMAIL },
                            new int[] { R.id.ContactTitle, R.id.Name, 
                                    R.id.MainPhone, R.id.CellPhone, R.id.Fax, R.id.Email });
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

        }
```

Would love it if someone could help me out with this issue or get me pointed in the right direction. Thanks again for you time!

Comment: Are You sure that You get different rows from the server?

Comment: Its a best practice to use Adapter class to populate the listview..U can try for that..

Comment: sandrstar- Yes, because it passes through my for loop and making the two elements their just not what i told it to look like. If that even makes sense.

Comment: subburaj- could you please explain what you mean in more detail please?

Comment: I think that, in order to work this out, we're going to need to see the code that generates the logo at the bottom of the list.  Is it in a layout somewhere?

Comment: @ G. Blake Meike- there is no logo in the ListView, could you please reference what your referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're specifying the wrong layout for the adapter to use. Either that or eclipse's generated resources have gotten confused and you should do a clean.

Also, for what it's worth:
You should do the parsing and map generation in doInBackground, modify the return value to be of type Map and call publishProgress(hashMap) with each mapping. Then in onProgressUpdate(Map... values) you could add the map to the ArrayList and issue adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to inform it of new data.

Comment: I cleaned it but am re-building the XML layout for the list items real quick. Could you explain your way of doing this in more detail? i have not developed too much with the AsyncTask but would like to know more.

Comment: onPostExecute is invoked on the UI thread (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You shouldn't do any work on the UI thread and should off load it to a background thread - which is the purpose of AsyncTasks to begin with.

Comment: I understand that much, that's why i do my service request in the background. What your saying is i should also move the parsing to the background as well? I also use onProgressUpdate should it be onUpdateProgress()? Looking into your statement and my code more i see exactly what your saying and changing that now.....Would allow it to preform and handle way better.